# How to print value after enabledelayedexpansion

Tags: batch-file

Setting a variable in a "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" works with

```
set HASGCC=0    
for /f "delims=" %%i in (...) do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set HASGCC=1
        endlocal
    )
```

but sadly a echo after doesn't result in the correct value (always 0).

```
   echo Finished %HASGCC%
```

Afterwards

```
if !HASGCC! == 0  >>"%PREFS_F...
```

is evaluated correct.

How to print correct value.

```
echo Finished !HASGCC!
```

results in

> Finished !HASGCC!

Comment: You shouldn't enable delayed expansion in your code, it makes no sense there. Or enable before the loop

Comment: Please observe that I deleted some lines to make it a bit shorter.

Comment: But why do you think to need to toggle the mode inside the FOR-loop?

Comment: I think I don't get the correct values for %%i inside the loop when I don't set the mode.

Comment: It's possible, but only if `%%i` contains exclamation marks. But then you need to add some more context to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setlocal` with or without `EnableDelayedExpansion` creates a new scope for variables.
It makes a copy of all variables and then all changes are made to these copies.
An `endlocal` leaves this scope and discard the copy and all changes are dsicarded.

For some variable manipulations you have to enable delayed expansion for some it's better to use disabled delayed expansion, but the only way to switch between them is to use `setlocal`.

But in your case it seems, that you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by removing

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

but don't know why.